# Triple quotes in Jmeter http-requests to ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, jmeter

I am testing ElasticSearch with Jmeter tool and can't yet solve the case with incorrect http-requests string quoting.

My Pipeline:

1. read csv file
2. make query to ElasticSearch

Test dataset contains strings with double quote inside.
In this case I am using triple quoting.

For example,

QUERY_1

```
{
    "query":
    {
        "match":
        {
            "title":
            {
                "query": """Green apple" fresh"""
            }
        }
    }
}
```

RESPONSE_1

```
"caused_by":{"type":"json_parse_exception",
"reason":"Unexpected character ('\"' (code 34)): 
was expecting comma to separate Object entries\n at [
Source: (org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.AbstractBytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper)
```

The error occurs due to the ' " ' symbol.

If I run the same query in Kibana, the answer is correct.

I am using for request Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

Encoding in jmeter system.properties:

```
- file.encoding=UTF-8
- file.encoding.pkg=sun.io
- sun.io.unicode.encoding=UnicodeBig
- sun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
```

And also

```
Jmeter ver.:        5.3
ElasticSearch ver.: 7.9
```

Is it possible to fix this case without data preprocessing ?

Will appreciate any advice !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the backslash before the double quote  `\"` inside the value

```
{
"query":
{
    "match":
    {
        "title":
        {
            "query": "Green apple\" fresh"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Janesh, thx. 
I am trying to figure out how to set up Jmeter pre-processor for solving this case.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved without triple quoting through the JSR223 PreProcessor with groovy script:

```
def title_escaped = vars.get("title").replaceAll('\\"','');
vars.put('title_escaped', title_escaped);
```

Thanks to @Janesh for the finding.